# How to Upload file to google drive only if it is not exist?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, google-drive-api

I use xcode to develope iphone application.

i upload Database files to my google drive with this code.

```
- (void)uploadDB{
    GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
    file.title = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"User:%@DB.sqlite",UserName];
    file.descriptionProperty = @"Uploaded from  iOS ";
    file.mimeType = @"application/x-sqlite3";


    // Attach a DB file to the email

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                          documentsDirectory,DB_File];
    NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName];


    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:file.mimeType];
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                                       uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

    UIAlertView *waitIndicator = [self showWaitIndicator:@"Uploading to Google Drive"];

    [self.driveService executeQuery:query
                  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                      GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error) {
                      [waitIndicator dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                      if (error == nil)
                      {
                          NSLog(@"File ID: %@", insertedFile.identifier);
                          [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"File saved!"];
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
                          [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"Sorry, an error occurred!"];
                      }
                  }];

}
```

My problem that it is always save it as a new file, I wand that it will check if this file name exist on drive and replace it.

Thanks

Comment: How can i check the resource id of the file that located on Drive?

Answer (score 0):

The title of a file in Drive is not unique.  Instead, you should use the resource id.  The first time you upload the database file, remember the resource id that it gives back to you on success and then update that from then on.

Comment: I new with this SDk, how i can get resource id?

Comment: How can i check the resource id of the file that located on Drive?